# Easiest way to print without breakline

Tags: printing, factorization

So I have factorized a transfer function and stored the terms in a variable. I want to print the product of terms without Mathematica joining them and without a break line. I have managed the first, but I am having the trouble with the second. Here is a small workable example, if someone can help me please.

```
TFilterListFactorized={{(1.05925 s)/(100324. + 1. s), (1.05925 s^2)/(
  1.00649*10^10 + 100324. s + 1. s^2)}}
    
For[i = 1, i <= Length[TFilterListFactorized], i++,
     For[j = 1, j <= Length[TFilterListFactorized[[i]]] - 1, j++,
      Print[TFilterListFactorized[[i]][[j]], "\[Times]"]
      ];
     Print[TFilterListFactorized[[i]][[-1]]]
     ]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have a list of expressions that are all the factors of a larger expression. And you want to print the product without evaluating it.

One way of doing this is to use "HoldForm":

```
list={(1.05925 s)/(100324. + 1. s), (1.05925 s^2)/(1.00649*10^10 + 
    100324. s + 1. s^2)};

Times@@(HoldForm/@list)
```

[image]

If you want additionally an "x" between terms:

```
Row[HoldForm /@ Riffle[list, "x"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a display, something like this might work:

```
Row[TFilterListFactorized[[1]], "\[Times]"]
```

Or more generally when the list is longer:

```
Row[#, "\[Times]"] & /@ TFilterListFactorized
```

And you could introduce other things like Column or TableForm.